# Rails n:1 relation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it's such an easy thing, but I'm not able to find what's wrong. I have a model User (Devise) who has many features. Looks like this:

/app/model/user.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :features
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
      # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
      attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :date_of_birth, :gender, :password_confirmation
      # attr_accessible :title, :body

      validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => ['female', 'male'], message: 'not selected'
      validates :first_name, presence: true
      validates :last_name, presence: true
      validates_date :date_of_birth, :on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }
    end
```

/app/model/feature.rb

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :content, :hits, :icon, :images, :lable, :rank, :success, :user_id
end
```

But the Rails magic doesn't work at all:

```
rails console
user = User.create(email: 'test@test.de', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test', first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'Test', date_of_birth: '1992-12-21 00:00:00.000000', gender: 'male')
feature = user.feature.create(content: 'First Feature', hits: 5, icon: 'icon-bell', images: null, lable: 'Bell', rank: 1, success: 3)
```

Returns the error among others:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `feature' for #<User:0x4b377b8>
```

I read through so many posts, but I couldn't find any mistake. Can someone give me a hint, I think its such a stupid error I made. Thanks!

Comment: you probably mean `features`, not feature. User has many *features*. So call user.features.create()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do

```
feature = user.features.create(content: 'First Feature', hits: 5, icon: 'icon-bell', images: null, lable: 'Bell', rank: 1, success: 3)
```

because a user has_many :features when creating a feature for a user you have to type features instead of feature

```
feature = user.features.create
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I just have to add a user.save before I could add a feature to it. But what ist wrong, when the Feature Controller doesn't work at all? It always set the user_id to null and in the controller itself, there is no access to the @user Object. The controller was generated by rails g scaffold ... . The function, which prepares the save of the values in the create method ist "@feature = Feature.new(params[:feature])".

Comment: One note more: It works, when i add the line "@feature.user_id = current_user.id" under "@feature = Feature.new(params[:feature])", but why did it work in the console withput?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean by console withput but from what I understand you are having trouble setting the user_id.As you said you can do @feature.user_id = current_user.id or you can try doing something like current_user.features.create in features#create